# Finding blank fields in an object - C#

Tags: c#

We have a scenario where in if an entity exists between the source and target, we are supposed to merge data in the target i.e. copy values from foundation columns where the target column is blank.

We are using WCF servcie calls and we have the entity objects.

If i have an entity lets say `Staff`, staff conatins the basic properties for name, etc and we have a list for `StaffAddress`, `StaffEmail`, and `StaffPhone`.

So I just wanted to know is there a way using LINQ or any other mechanism - I can find out the list of property on the `Staff` object which are null or blank ?

One rudimentary way is to of course manually check one property by one which is blank ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it with LINQ

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FindBlankFields(Staff staff)
{
    return staff.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(p => p.CanRead)
        .Select(p => new { Property = p, Value = p.GetValue(staff, null) })
        .Where(a => a.Value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Value.ToString()))
        .Select(a => a.Property.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could get all the properties through reflection, and then call GetValue on each PropertyInfo instance.  Where it is null, you would return the PropertyInfo:

```
static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetNullProperties(object obj)
{
  // Get the properties and return only the ones where GetValue
  // does not return null.
  return 
    from pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties(
      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    where pi.GetValue(obj, null) != null
    select pi;
}
```

Mind you, this will return only public properties on the type, not non public properties.

Comment: Also, I don't believe this will tell you if a string is empty. But this could easily be modified to do that.

Comment: There's no need to specify the BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public here.  That's the default.

Comment: @David Morton: No, it is not the default.  Static properties will be included as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use some reflection for this:

```
var unsetProperties = from prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()
            let value = prop.GetValue(foo, null)
            where value == null || value.Equals(string.Empty)
            select prop.Name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will get static properties as well, which I don't think the poster wants.